# Dip bar width to involve chest

Tags: chest, triceps, dips

I go to a nearby park and do dips on parallel bars. I try to do them with my elbows not flared out i.e. tucked by my side. I feel my triceps getting engaged a lot but I don't feel it in my chest. Is it the width of the parallel bars? They are not too wide apart.

I am thinking of trying it out with my bar stools as that would allow me to adjust the width. Is it true that the more the width in the dip setup the more it engages chest? Please let me know.

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to engage your chest during dips, lean forward slightly. It doesn't really have to do with the width of the bars, rather the angle of your lean. That being said, leaning forward will still work your triceps as well.

See [this article](http://www.t-nation.com/free_online_article/most_recent/all_about_dips&cr=) for some good info on dips.

[image]